# Using Node.js on my fish / cygwin shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, cygwin, fish

I am following a course and on the learning process so apologies if any of this is simple!

I have installed the fish shell on cygwin through the cygwin installer as an option. I also have node (and npm) installed.

However, when typing 'node' in the shell, it just hangs and does not show the next line to use node instead?

Any help to get this working would be really appreciated!

[Please see the image of my terminal response here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3gjK.png)

Answer (score 1):

`node` run by itself drops you into an interpreter.

Does ctrl c print this message?

`(To exit, press ^C again or type .exit)`

What if you do this:

`node -e 'console.log("foo")'`

I get:

`node -e 'console.log("foo")'
foo`

What about if you just start typing

`node`

[press enter]

type in:

`console.log('foo')`

[press enter]